# SQL Server SUM of Multiple rows with where and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `SQL` table `Details` with columns name `ITEMS`,`TotalOrder`,`CancelOrder`

I write query like this

```
select Items, SUM(TotalOrder) as [TotalOrder], SUM(CancelOrder)as [CancelOrder] ,Source from Details group by Items
```

and the result appears to be like this

```
  ITEMS        TotalOrder    CancelOrder 
  Laptop         102            5
  Desktop        9              1
  Tablet         17             0
  Tshirt         119            12
  TV             5              0
```

But my column name `Items` with data `Laptop`,`Desktop`,`Tablet` are same with name as `Laptop`, that's why I wish to get output like

```
  ITEMS        TotalOrder    CancelOrder 
  Laptop         128            6
  Tshirt         119            12
  TV             5              0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select Items, SUM(TotalOrder) as [TotalOrder], SUM(CancelOrder)as [CancelOrder] 
from Details 
where Items NOT IN('Laptop','Desktop','Tablet')  group by Items 
UNION 
select 'Laptop',SUM(TotalOrder) as [TotalOrder], SUM(CancelOrder)as [CancelOrder] 
from Details 
where Items IN('Laptop','Desktop','Tablet')
```

Comment: @SS8 I'm glad that I came for your help.